# TypeError : res.status is not a function returning Login message and Token

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, jwt

i am getting this as error

```
TypeError : res.status is not a function
```

I do not know why, but i am getting this Error

My code is looking thus :

```
app.post('/api/v1/user/login', async function(req,res){

    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    dbConn.query(`SELECT * FROM XXXXXXXXX_users WHERE email = ${dbConn.escape(req.body.email)};`,(err,result)=>{
        if(err){
            throw err;
            return res.status(400).send({message: err,})
        }
        if(!result.length){
            return res.status(400).send({message: 'Username and password incorrect!',})
        }
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,result[0]['password'],(err,res)=>{
            if(err){
                throw err;
                return res.status(400).send({message: 'Username and password Incorrect!'});
            }
            if(result){
                const token = jwt.sign({email: result[0].email,id:result[0].id},'the-super-strong-secrect',{ expiresIn: '1h' });
                return res.status(200).send({message: 'OK', token}) // Error is here
                
            }
            return res.status(400).send({message: 'User and pass incorrect'})
        })
    })
 })
```

I am trying to implement Login system backend API please I would like to know why this is not working as its supposed to. Kindly help. A bit new to this

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in this line

```
bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,result[0]['password'],(err,res) //<-- Using res keyword here
```

See how you are using `(err, res)` for this callback. This interferes with

```
app.post('/api/v1/user/login', async function(req,res) //<-- Also using res keyword here
```

I would suggest you to use `async/await` for better cleanup.

```
app.post('/api/v1/user/login', async function(req, res) {

                let email = req.body.email;
                let password = req.body.password;

                try {
                    const queryResult = await dbConn.query(`SELECT * FROM XXXXXXXXX_users WHERE email = ${dbConn.escape(req.body.email)};`)

                        if (!queryResult.length) {
                            return res.status(400).send({
                                message: 'Username and password incorrect!',
                            })
                        }

                        const compareResult = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, queryResult[0]['password'])

                        if (compareResult) {
                            const token = jwt.sign({
                                email: queryResult[0].email,
                                id: queryResult[0].id
                            }, 'the-super-strong-secrect', {
                                expiresIn: '1h'
                            });
                            return res.status(200).send({
                                message: 'OK',
                                token
                            })

                        }
                        return res.status(400).send({
                            message: 'User and pass incorrect'
                        })

                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        res.status(500).json({
                            err
                        });
                    }
```